# Language changes when I change page in magento

Tags: magento

I have one problem in my site. I have two languages installed, Portuguese and English(default). On my front end when i change from English to Portuguese it makes it all right but when I switch page (for example, try to see one category) it switches back again to English language.

I've tried to change cookie lifetime and some other things but didn't work.

What can I do in order to "save" the language selected and keep it on every pages that I try to access?

Comment: Try to save the choosen language in the user session is the best way i guess

Comment: Please show some code you are trying to use to maintain the language state across your site

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two different store views in your magento install one for english and one for Portuguese.